# After installing KB 4340556 Outlook 2013 COM add in stops loading

Tags: outlook-addin

The problematic patch was released as rollup KB 4340556 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4340556/security-and-quality-rollup-updates-for-net-framework-3-5-1-4-5-2-4-6

The specific patch number is KB 4338423
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4338423/description-of-the-security-and-quality-rollup-updates-for-net-framewo

After installing this patch the add-in is always non-active with the error:
Location:          mscoree.dll
Load Behavior : Not loaded. A runtime error occurred during the loading of the COM Add-in.

Add-in was developed in C# .Net 3.5.1; not signed .

Run in: 
Office 2013 32 bit;
OS: Windows 7 SP1

**After uninstalling KB 4338423 add-in works OK.**

Answer (score 0):

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4338612/description-of-the-security-only-update-for-net-framework-3-5-1-for-wi

> **Known issues**
>
> After you install any of the July 2018 .NET Framework Security Updates, a COM >component fails to load because of “access denied,” “class not registered,” or >“internal failure occurred for unknown reasons” errors. 
>   
>   **Status**
>   Microsoft is aware of this issue and is actively working on a solution.  We will >update this article when there is any new information about the issue.
>   https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4345913/access-denied-errors-after->installing-july-2018-security-rollup-update

> **Workaround**
>       Temporarily uninstall the  [July 2018 .NET Framework Security Updates](https://portal.msrc.microsoft.com/en-US/security-guidance/advisory/CVE-2018-8356) to restore functionality until a new update is released to resolve this problem.